# iText: missing characters when converting PDF to Text

Tags: pdf, itext

I am Trying to extract the text from the [this pdf](http://www.kabupro.jp/edp/20100628/S000607V.pdf) using the LocationTextExtractionStrategy.class, but for some reason a number of characters are being dropped during the parsing.

On the first page of the original .pdf;

```
    【表紙】
    【提出書類】有価証券報告書
    【根拠条文】金融商品取引法第24条第１項
    【提出先】近畿財務局長
    【提出日】平成22年６月28日
    【事業年度】第27期（自　平成21年４月１日　至　平成22年３月31日）
    【会社名】株式会社カネミツ
    【英訳名】KANEMITSU CORPORATION
```

Resulting text output has numbers such as 22,28 and the english text "KANEMATSU" missing;

```
    【表紙】
    【提出書類】 有価証券報告書
    【根拠条文】 金融商品取引法第条第１項
    【提出先】 近畿財務局長
    【提出日】 平成年６月日
    【事業年度】 第期（自　平成年４月１日　至　平成年３月日）
    【会社名】 株式会社カネミツ
    【英訳名】
```

Here's the code...

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceFileUrl);
    String strategyClass =         “com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy.class”

    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    for(int I = 1; I < n; i++) {
    TextExtractionStrategy strategy = (TextExtractionStrategy) Class.forName(strategyClass).newInstance();
            String text = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i,strategy);
    …
    }
```

I have reviewed other questions of a similar nature on SO, [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773914/itext-pdftextextractor-missing-ligatures-in-resulting-text) is similar although i am able to copy the text from the pdf directly so this is probably a different issue.

Comment: I can't help you, but I found the documentation for anyone else that wants to try: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/PdfTextExtractor.html

Comment: I can´t run your code now but the chars look like they are half width types. You are not getting anything, even unprintable?

Comment: I think the missing text is added using the wrong encoding and maybe Adobe Reader deals with this error. The missing text is supposed to be in the same font, but a visual check leads to believe that this isn't the case.