# pdfbox: garbled japanese txt output

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfbox

This is related to a similar [question on iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29254678/itext-missing-characters-when-converting-pdf-to-text), but relates to pdfbox (using version 1.8.6), so I am posting another question here.

As in the other link, I am trying to convert [this pdf](http://www.kabupro.jp/edp/20100628/S000607V.pdf) into txt. The original pdf has text

```
【表紙】
【提出書類】有価証券報告書
【根拠条文】金融商品取引法第24条第１項
【提出先】近畿財務局長
【提出日】平成22年６月28日
【事業年度】第27期（自　平成21年４月１日　至　平成22年３月31日）
【会社名】株式会社カネミツ
【英訳名】KANEMITSU CORPORATION
```

The code I am using is as follows;

```
String fileName = "S000607V.pdf"; 
PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(fileName));
if(pdf.isEncrypted()){pdf.decrypt("");}
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
Writer output = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
stripper.writeText(pdf, output);
```

Which gives garbled output as per the below.

```
    ????
    ?????? ???????
    ?????? ????????24????
    ????? ??????
    ????? ??22???28?
    ?????? ?27??????21??????????22???31??
    ????? ????????
    ????? KANEMITSU CORPORATION
```

What is interesting is that pdfbox returns the half-width alphanumeric numbers ("24", "22", "KANEMITSU"), whereas the [iText output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29254678/itext-missing-characters-when-converting-pdf-to-text), returns the Japanese characters, but not the alphanumeric characters that appear here.

I had similar issues with other pdf's when using pdfbox version 1.8.5, although this was [resolved in 1.8.6 following this bug fix](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1895). The issue presented here seems unrelated.

Comment: I tried with 1.8.9 (the current version) where it doesn't work. However it works with the unreleased version 2.0, which one can get with svn. https://pdfbox.apache.org/downloads.html#scm

Comment: i have a similar problem nowadays with pdfbox , and i used itext to write arabic text , and i just tested it , and its writing arabic numbers with no problems .

Comment: please post your code using itext to print the alphanumeric  characters

Comment: Tilman's suggestion worked. pdfbox 1.8.9 was unable to resolve the Mincho font type, but when run using 2.0 I get the warning "WARNING: Using fallback font 'CourierNewPSMT' for 'Mincho'", and the output is as expected. Thank you.